# Is there a free Ubuntu Studio 20.10 instruction manual available?

Tags: 20.10, ubuntu-studio, documentation

Can someone provide a link for *French (or English) **Ubuntu Studio 20.10** Detailed Instruction Manual*? (preferably a free .pdf).

I am new to Linux, coming from Windows (xp, 7, 10).

Ubuntu Studio is hard to configure for my setup, it doesn't work plug&play like Windows.
Every module or option affects the whole system (bugs + crashes frequently when I make a change). It's hard to understand how the apps/modules work together and what/how to configure without creating a mess (manual shutdowns are to avoid!).

Searching the web (Google, AskUbuntu, Wikis, forums, etc) for info but doesn't give desired results: most of it is for older versions, not in my setup language, asks for command installs from PPA backports (not recommended apparently) or simply irrelevant.

English info is easier to find, french wikis are outdated or under construction (blank page) and resources found on my install didn't help much (some web-links were broken), neither did the in-app manuals.

My configuration is not optimal: solved audio for most but not all apps, video is near resolved but not as good as with Windows. I hope I can fix this.

Some apps don't have the features expected: for instance, for DVD ripping K3b didn't have transcode installed and I read that the module wasn't supported in my distro, so I had to install Handbrake (works like a charm but doesn't appear in the drop-down menu when I plug in my DVD player/recorder).

My setup is french, but some bits and modules are still in english, maybe I can fix that too, plus other useful tweaks I might want.

Thanks.

Comment: It would probably be a better path to research/ask about the actual problems you are experiencing. I'm not sure what good an instruction manual would do.  Here is the [community user guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/UserGuide).  This goes over the basics of how to use the operating system. I doubt that a French translation would be helpful.

Comment: @Nmath https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/UserGuide/SystemConfiguration yields "add text here"... There is no documentation for 20.10 regarding my problems. Manual would be useful to understand what different parameters do and what options I should use.

Comment: Did you search on Ask Ubuntu about the problems you have?  Did you search for info about the "parameters" you are trying to figure out? You haven't said anything specific about the problems you are experiencing, so it's hard to direct you to the right place.  If the information you are looking for isn't available for any version, why would it be in documentation specific to 20.10?  (Why would your problem even exist in documentation?)  I recommend that you **ask about the actual problem(s) that you face**. Otherwise this is very much an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)

Comment: @Nmath Ubuntu parameters are for all versions? So I can search "ubuntu studio" + keywords + module version number to get better results? I might not have right settings for audio: posted a question about that. Hope it's better formulated  than the 1rst. Waiting for answers is long, trying stuff crashes the system. Manuals explain everything installed with all module/parameter/setting options, it's faster to select the best one for me.

Comment: @Nmath I found https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio has better info than the 1rst link you gave me wich is under construction. I had to click on USER GUIDE. Thanks for your comments, it helps.

Answer (score 0):

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/groovy/+package/manpages-fr

Has all the french Manuals for Groovy Gorilla OS and CPUs.
Page also mentions: "The English package manpages contains additional manual pages which have not been translated yet."

The last "s390x" link I found first on Google was not a secured link, but was readable from Firefox.

The one for my CPU had "_all.deb" debian file for download: I don't know what to do with it (probably needs to be compiled into something readable, didn't appear in my Documents).

I searched "manpages-fr" in Discover and installed it.

Other Ubuntu flavor translations can be found here:
https://translations.launchpad.net/ubuntu
but it is probably better for a new user like me to search with Discover "manpages-" + 2 letters (language abbreviation name).